# Flutter : emulator not work get error with gradle

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I want to run flutter app with (VSCode or Android studio) ,for both I get this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: The device is not ready

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by running these commands :

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade --force
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Got mine running with this:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

type `flutter clean` in the terminal and then wait. After the successful execution of the previous command, type `flutter pub get` to fetch all dependencies needed.